# how to solve Timeouts are not supported on this stream in entity framework core to convert html string to pdf by using puppter library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, puppeteer

Can anyone explain me how to solve timeout is not supported on this stream for after   return new FileStreamResult here how it generating pdf,im not able to get the pdf for this code.

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GeneratePDFAsync(string templatedetails)
        {
            using var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
            await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true

            });
            Stream stream;
            using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
            {
                await page.SetContentAsync(templatedetails);
                var result = await page.GetContentAsync();
                page.DefaultNavigationTimeout = 0;
                stream = (await page.PdfStreamAsync());
            }
            var mimeType = "application/pdf";
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType) 
            {
                FileDownloadName = "test.pdf" 
            };
        }
```

Comment: I reckon here you have two solutions: 1. increase the `DefaultNavigationTimeout` value to see if it makes any difference. 2. Another possible solution is to use a different overload of the `FileStreamResult` constructor that takes a `buffer` instead of a `stream`.